# Flex - how do I sort a datagrid column that is using an item renderer in the header?

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid

I am using an advanced data grid that is using a custom item renderer for the column heading and now sorting doesn't work. If I take out the custom renderer it works fine but I need it to work with the renderer. Does anyone know how to do this? I am new to Flex and ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a sortCompareFunction for the DataGrid column:

For example:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Foo" dataField="bar" sortCompareFunction="compareTypes">
```

Lets just pretend that this DataGridColumn as an inline item renderer...

And then the function is defined as follows:

```
public static function compareTypes(typeOne:Object, typeTwo:Object):int
{
    return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(String(typeOne.foo), String(typeTwo.foo));
}
```

Comment: For a Spark DataGrid, the answer is almost the same however the sortCompareFunction takes three parameters. The third is the GridColumn object. 

It's documented here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc3647f39ab2512d530e9965-8000.html